# Solving restricted/one-sided limits

Tags: limits

> Is the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^{2} - 9}$ continuous at $x = 3$?

I tried to check by solving each requirement for continuity, which are the following:

1. The limit at the point must exist;
2. The function at the point must exist;
3. The limit at the point must be equal to the function at the point.

The second requirement can be easily checked as 'satisfied' as $f(3) = 0$. Thus, I only need to check if the first requirement is satisfied.

I started by solving for the left-hand limit as follows:
\[L^{-} = \lim_{x \to 3^{-}}\left[\sqrt{x^{2} - 9}\right]\]

Then, I eventually got $L^{-}$ to be zero.

---

My question is this: Is it correct to rewrite the problem by substituting $x = 3 - a$, where $a \geqslant 0$, then solving for the limit as $a$ approaches zero?

---

Edit: This is a question about solving one-sided limits, and not about the continuity of the square root function.

Comment: It is correct, for this case.

Comment: You've used the notation for a limit from the left (from below), but when $x \lt 3$, the expression $\sqrt{x^2 - 9}$ is not well-defined (as taking the square root of a negative number.  Perhaps you meant for $x$ to approach $3$ from above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About substitutions in limits in general:**

In general, that's absolutely right (here, in particular, something more important is to be noted. See the Addendum). $x\to 3^-$ can be thought of as $x = 3-h$ where $h\to 0^+$ or $x = 3+h$ where $h\to 0^-$. Guess what, that's exactly the substitution you made.

*Subtle point to note:* You say $x = 3-a$, where $a\ge 0$. While that is perfectly fine (in general it is fine, but for this particular case please check the addendum), I just want to mention that $a > 0$ is no problem either. When talking about $\lim\limits_{a\to 0^+}f(a)$ for some $f$, $a$ is **approaching** $0$ from the positive side, but is **never equal to** $0$. Hence, $a>0$ suffices and the substitution $x = 3-a$ works.

Before making substitutions though, one must be extremely careful about the domain of the function.

---

**Addendum/Warning:**
The domain of $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-9}$ is $x^2 \ge 9$, i.e. $|x| \ge 3$ or $x \in (-\infty,-3]\cup [3,\infty)$. So, it does not make sense to talk about the left hand limit at $3$, since values immediately to the left of $3$ are not in the domain of $f$. You may ask, does $$\lim_{x\to 3} \sqrt{x^2-9}$$ still exist? Yes, it does! This is because the only one-sided limit we can even talk about at $3$ is the right-handed one. We define the limit at $3$ to be equal to this one-sided limit.

Comment: Can I ask if the limit exists and is equal to zero?

Comment: Please see my edit @soupless. It should clarify things further.

Comment: Does that mean that I used limits wrong, but I got the answer _somehow_ correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of the case here. To find the limit, you are generally supposed to find the left-hand and right-hand limit both, see if they are equal, and that's your answer. When one of the two limits doesn't make sense (like in our case, the left-handed one at $3$), you simply evaluate the one-sided limit that *does make sense* and call that the limit of your function at that point. Sounds good?

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to evaluate for left-hand limit simply because it does not belong to the domain of the function. In general for obtaining continuity of boundary point we consider the limiting value of the function as the value of the one-sided limit. Thus if,

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+}f(x)=f(3)$$

you can say that the function is continuous at $x=3$. as the function is defined only for $|x|\ge3$ assuming you are working over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I am working over $\mathbb{R}$. Also, I didn't quite get your answer because we need to prove that it is continuous at $x = 3$, thus stating where $f$ is defined for values of $x$ will not help.

Comment: I was basically saying that as the function is not defined in $-3<x<3$ we cannot argue that we are approaching x=3 from left since that is logically incorrect as we are square rooting a negative number for a real valued function.